# Understanding useEffect behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called StudentPage which shows the details of a student depending on the current student logged in `currentStudent` . The `currentStudent` object doesn't hold all the attributes of the Student model, so I fetch all the `students` with an axios request and get the `student` which matches the `curresntStudent` by id, and get all the attributes I need from it.

Now the problem is when I try to access the value of a `student` property, I get the error "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**".
So I **console.log**- `students`, `currentStudent`, and `student` and noticed that when I try to access the `currentStudent.name` (*commented below*), the **console.log**-`students` outputs the list of students from my db, also noticed that the output of **console.log**-`student` object matches that of `currentStudent`. However, when I try to access `student.name` (*code below*), the **console.log** outputs shows an empty array for the students list causing the `student` object to be undefined.

Can anyone please help explain why I am noticing this behaviour, perhaps some concept of useEffect that I don't yet understand.

```
const StudentPage=({currentStudent, students, fetchStudents})=>{

useEffect(()=>{
        fetchStudents();
    },[]) //I tried making currentStudent a dependency [currentStudent] but same behaviour ocurs.

console.log(students);
console.log(currentStudent)

const student= students.filter(pupil=>{return(pupil.id===currentStudent.id)})[0]
console.log(student)

// return (<div>name: {currentStudent.name}</div>) this works normally but currentUser doesn't have all attributes i need
return(
<div>Name: {student.name}</div>                                     
)

const mapStateToProps= state=>{
return {
        students: state.students
       }
 }

export default(mapStateToProps,{fetchStudents})(StudentPage);
```

Comment: You're trying to filter an array that is not defined before the mounting of the component. try to declare your `student` variable as a state and populate your state after fetching `students`

Comment: student cannot be available on initial render because it’s retrieved asynchronously. This isn’t related to useEffect but to how JS works. If students is empty array before useEffect(), it has no chance to become full array at student=students... line. student can ===undefined, the layout needs to use conditions based onthis fact

Comment: const [student, setStudent] = useState(null);

and when you are calling the  API use async-await
const students =  fetchStudents();
setStudent( students.filter(pupil=>{return(pupil.id===currentStudent.id)})[0])

and then add the check in return
{student ? <div>Name: {student.name}</div>   : <div/>}

Comment: Also, do you really need (mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToprops) while working with hooks? I don't think so.

Comment: Also, the obvious problem here is that you shouldn't trust console output for debugging purposes because it outputs a reference to the object and doesn't reflect its realtime state. If you want to see the latter, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(students))`.

Comment: I am using redux to manage my state (both currentStudent and students are gotten from the redux store). I **resolved** my issue by simply adding this line `{student && student.name}` to check if student is null or not. Adding the above line of code was the only change I made to my code. Is anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here you can find an example on how to do what you want](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-goodall-b9hoh?file=/src/StudentPage.jsx):

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export function StudentPage({ studentId, fetchStudents }) {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const students = await fetchStudents();
      const currentStudent = students.find((student) => {
        console.log(student);
        return student.id === studentId;
      });
      setStudent(currentStudent);
    })();
  }, [studentId, fetchStudents]);

  return (
    <>
      Student ID: {studentId}, Student name: {student && student.name}
    </>
  );
}
```

`useEffect` will be triggered whenever the dependency (`studentId` in this case) changes, including on first render. You should store you value in state (using `useState`) and have the necessary checks in place to see whether it is null or not.

Comment: I am using redux to manage my state (both currentStudent and students are gotten from the redux store). I **resolved** my issue by simply adding this line `{student && student.name}` to check if student is null or not. Adding the above line of code was the only change I made to my code. Is anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: No that's okay, using `{ student && student.name }` is a common approach, you could also use the [`get` function from `lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/#get): `{ _.get(student, 'name') }` if you are planning to reference a lot of values and don't want to do the `student &&` check everytime.